# Magento Admin shows product as disabled but getStatus() method says product is enabled

Tags: magento-1.9

My code shows a particular product as **enabled** while at the same time the magento admin/products panel says it is **disabled**. 
Are there two fields controlling its enabled/disabled status?
Any insights would be welcome.
Thanks in advance.

(My code below is a paraphrased from my actual code, but the crux bit is the same)

Code Snippet:

```
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','sku','price','special_price','final_price','product_status','special_to_date'))
    ->load();

    foreach ($products as $product) {  

           $zeroPriceZeroSpecialCount ++;

           $zeroPriceZeroSpecialHtml .= '<br>' . $zeroPriceZeroSpecialCount . 
                '  Name = '  . $product->getName(). 
                '  SKU = ' .$product->getSku(). 
                '  Status = ' .$product->getStatus(). 
                '  Price = ' . $product->getPrice() . 
                '  Special Price = ' . $product->getSpecialPrice() . 
                '  Final Price =  ' . $product->getFinalPrice() . 
                '  Special price To Date = ' .$product->getSpecialTODate(). 
                '<br>';
   }

  echo($zeroPriceZeroSpecialHtml);
```

My output:

> 14 Name = Dynamite Baits - Strawberry And Ice Cream Liquid 250ml SKU =
>   **Status = 1** Price = 7.9900 Special Price = Final Price = 7.99 Special
>   price To Date

What Magento Admin/Manage Products Says:
[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a multistore and it is turned on on store base.
The setting can be changed per store.
In the upperleft you can switch between them, check for the store you are visiting on the frontend.

If you do not have a multisite(you cannot switch in the upperleft between them), please take a look in the database (`catalog_entity_int`) for the product id `entity_id` and `attribute_id` for `status`(probably 96), because after importing it can happen that status is only set for a specific store and not global, remove the record and set global status again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading whole collection load the specific product and then print product data like below:

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(productid);
    var_dump($product->getData());
```

And check the values

Answer (score -1):

Try with this "$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()"

Comment: Hi, didn't work I'm afraid. Same result as before.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
```

Load(2) is the id of the category you are trying to get.